# explicit specialization of template class member function

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, specialization

I need to specialize template member function for some type (let's say **double**). It works fine while class `X` itself is not a template class, but when I make it template GCC starts giving compile-time errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template <class C> class X
{
public:
   template <class T> void get_as();
};

template <class C>
void X<C>::get_as<double>()
{

}

int main()
{
   X<int> x;
   x.get_as();
}
```

here is the error message

```
source.cpp:11:27: error: template-id
  'get_as<double>' in declaration of primary template
source.cpp:11:6: error: prototype for
  'void X<C>::get_as()' does not match any in class 'X<C>'
source.cpp:7:35: error: candidate is:
  template<class C> template<class T> void X::get_as()
```

What is the problem here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: this is illegal in the current standard, to specialize, you have to specialize the class as well...

Comment: but it works if the class is not template. Is it illegal too?

Comment: nope, that is perfectly fine, it's only for class templates that this rule applies (AFAIK).

Answer (score 126, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. You would need to say the following, but it is **not** correct

```
template <class C> template<>
void X<C>::get_as<double>()
{

}
```

Explicitly [specialized members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization#Members_of_specializations) need their surrounding class templates to be explicitly specialized as well. So you need to say the following, which would only specialize the member for `X<int>`.

```
template <> template<>
void X<int>::get_as<double>()
{

}
```

If you want to keep the surrounding template unspecialized, you have several choices. I prefer overloads

```
template <class C> class X
{
   template<typename T> struct type { };

public:
   template <class T> void get_as() {
     get_as(type<T>());
   }

private:
   template<typename T> void get_as(type<T>) {

   }

   void get_as(type<double>) {

   }
};
```

Comment: why do you need the `type<>` wrapper? couldn't a cast of a 0 to a pointer of type `T` do the trick? I guess it's not as elegant...

Comment: Looks like this is really not possible to do. Thanks.

Comment: @Nim right, I think the pointer cast thing is ugly, and wouldn't work for types you can't form pointers to (references). Also, having a function parameter be a pointer to an array type without a size is illegal in C++. Having it in a type wrapper makes it work for all types.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb : What are the other choices along overloads ? Can show some of them ?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Thanks! I love this answer! It's really elegant and an intriguing way of having it your way without making it too ugly of a hack... Could you just explain to me why the type<> wrapper is needed? I didn't quite get the comment from Nim but I'm so eager to understand what his comment was about and why this solution is better.. Thank you!!!

Comment: @fast-reflexes his comment was to use `template<typename T> void get_as(T*); void get_as(double*);` and pass a `(T*)0`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb In the current draft of the standard, I see that only the explicit specializations of **class template** members is prohibited if their enclosing class templates are not specialized as well (http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#17). Is there other paragraph in the standard which prohibits the explicit specialization of all members? Thank you.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I see that others have the same interpretation as yours. Am I reading that paragraph wrong? Thank you.

Comment: I did not see the point to do what you suggested right now. What you suggested need to declare the `get_as(type<double>)`  in template X. But normally we want to use template is just because we want allow lib users to declare `get_as()` for their own type. If you just want to specilize `get_as()` You can simply do that directly in class X if you are using c++17.

Answer (score 31):

If one is able to used `std::enable_if` we could rely on SFINAE (substitution failure is not an error)

that would work like so (see [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VnrupHUWOWvh2rY0)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename C> class X
{
public:
    template <typename T, 
              std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<double,T>, int> = 0> 
    void get_as() { std::cout << "get as T" << std::endl; }

    template <typename T, 
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<double,T>, int> = 0> 
    void get_as() { std::cout << "get as double" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
   X<int> d;
   d.get_as<double>();

   return 0;
}
```

The ugly thing is that, with all these enable_if's only one specialization needs to be available for the compiler otherwise disambiguation error will arise. Thats why the default behaviour "get as T" needs also an enable if.

Comment: Updated the post to make it more modern.

Answer (score 24):

Probably the cleanest way to do this in **C++17** and on-wards is to use a **`if constexpr` in combination with the `std::is_same_v` type trait** without explicitly specialisation at all:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename C>
class X {
  public:
    template <typename T> 
    void get_as() { 
      // Implementation part for all types
      std::cout << "get as ";

      // Implementation part for each type separately
      if constexpr (std::is_same_v<double, T>) {
        std::cout << "'double'";
      } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, T>) {
        std::cout << "'int'";
      } else {
        std::cout << "(default)";
      }

      // Implementation part for all types
      std::cout << std::endl;
      return;
    }
};

int main() {
  X<int> d {};
  d.get_as<double>(); // 'double'
  d.get_as<int>();    // 'int'
  d.get_as<float>();  // (default)

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xbP9Vy3T5NAiSJKs)

---

If you need to have a return type as well you could declare the **return type** as **`auto`**:

```
template <typename T> 
auto get_as() { 
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<double, T>) {
    return 0.5;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's very elegant and allows to have common parts for two specializations. Thanks!