# Template class with template function

Tags: c++, templates

Can anyone tell what is wrong with this piece of code?

```
template<class X>
class C {
public:
    template<class Y> void f(Y); // line 4
};

template<class X, class Y>
void C<X>::f(Y y) { // line 8
    // Something.
}

int main() {
    C<int> c;
    char a = 'a';
    c.f(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
$ g++ source.cpp 
source.cpp:8: error: prototype for ‘void C<X>::f(Y)’ does not match any in class ‘C<X>’
source.cpp:4: error: candidate is: template<class X> template<class Y> void C::f(Y)
```

I now that I can accomplish the task by declaring and defining the function at line 4, but what would be the consequences of declaring and defining the function at the same time compared to doing it separately? (This is not a discussion about declaring a function at header vs source file)

**Note:** I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512910/explicit-specialization-of-template-class-member-function) but is seems that the only part that interests me was left apart =(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The compiler already tells you the answer. The class `C` is a template with one parameter, and the member function `f` is a template member function, and you have to define it in the same way:

```
template <class X>
template <class Y>
void C<X>::f(Y y)
{
    // Something.
}
```

If you define the function at the declaration site, you'll implicitly declare it `inline`; that's about the only difference practically. There may be stylistic considerations, of course, e.g. never to put function definitions inside class definitions.

As you rightly observe, you will still have to provide the definition in the header file, since you will need to *instantiate* the template whenever you use it, and thus you need access to all the definitions.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! One more thing: why @"Johannes Schaub - litb" says at the accepted answer of the question linked at the note that this practice (at least I think that he was referring to "template<> template<>") is not correct?

Comment: @Freitass: I'm not sure what you're referring to (can you be more specific?), but the linked question is about *template specialization*, which you aren't doing in your situation.

Comment: Well, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512910/explicit-specialization-of-template-class-member-function/5513109#5513109) is the answer and I'm asking about the first line of the answer and the first chunk of code.

Comment: @Freitass: Again, that answer is about *specializing* the template parameter (the OP wanted to specialize the member template but not the class itself). How does this apply to you?

Comment: I just thought because both are related with template classes with template functions. Thanks for the `inline` part of your answer too (and again =D). I didn't have a clue about that.

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you exactly, your code should look like this:

```
template<class X>
class C {
public:
    template<class Y> void f(Y); // line 4
};

template<class X> template<class Y>
void C<X>::f(Y y) { // line 8
    // Something.
}

int main() {
    C<int> c;
    char a = 'a';
    c.f(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Your class is not defined as `template<class X, class Y>`

Answer (score -1):

As an aside, it's preferable to use the keyword 'typename' instead of 'class' inside a template argument list.

Comment: Yeah, I've read that too. But there's so many people using class.. I don't want to swim against the tide (at least not for this reason :P)

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.  Also, I'm not agreeing or disagreeing with you, but you should probably back your statement up with some facts as to why use of 'typename' is preferable to 'class'.

Comment: @andand: I coudn't agree more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213121/c-use-class-or-typename-for-template-parameters

Comment: is 'int' a class ? No. Will it be accepted as a template argument ? Yes. Is that ambiguous ? Yes. Can you prevent it ? Yes. Use 'typename'.

Comment: Many people prefer `class`. `typename` can legitimately appear with its other meaning in a template parameter list. At least `class` is unambiguous. Inside a template `class` just means "type". The standard almost universally uses `class`, not `typename`.