# Using template methods inside template classes

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Why is it expecting Struct1 and how do I format it so I can modify the properties in any struct?

I have 1 template class I'm using to modify data in 3 structs containing the same property names, they just happen to use different data types.

I'm trying to use a template method inside my template class, everything seems to be working as I expected it to with the template class upon the various instantiations.

```
GenericClass<Struct1> inventory[1000];
GenericClass<Struct2> machines[1000];
GenericClass<Struct3> physicalStructures[1000];
```

(yes I'm aware vectors exist, play along, I am including as little code as possible) That said, when I try to change one of the properties of the structs, I get an error stating that it is expecting the struct, rather than taking any datatype I hand it.

```
Main.cpp:39:28: error: no viable conversion from 'int' to 'Struct1'
inventory[0].setIdentifier(1);
```

I've checked these 3 references (and a few more), but they don't appear to do what I am in any of them.
[How to define template function within template class in *.inl file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659322/how-to-define-template-function-within-template-class-in-inl-file)

[Template class with template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015209/template-class-with-template-function)

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates

Here is a sample of my code.

```
template <class Type>
class GenericClass
{ 
private:
  Type Identifier;
public:
  void setIdentifier(Type Param);
  Type getIdentifier();
};


/* Struct prototypes
************************/
struct Struct1
{
private:
  int Identifier;
  string Description;
  float Value;
}

struct Struct2
{
private:
  long int Identifier;
  string Description;
  float Value;
};

struct Struct3
{
private:
 string Identifier;
 string Description;
 double Value;
};


int main()
{
  GenericRecord<Struct1> inventory[1000];
  GenericRecord<Struct2> machines[1000];
  GenericRecord<Struct3> physicalStructures[1000];
  inventory[0].setIdentifier(1);
}


template <class Type>
void GenericRecord<Type>::setIdentifier(Type Param)
{
  Identifier = Param;
}
template <class Type>
Type GenericRecord<Type>::getIdentifier()
{
  return Identifier;
}
```

The return method doesn't work either, I'm expecting that they are both failing for similar reasons.

Again, why is it expecting Struct1 and how do I format it so I can modify the properties in any struct?

Comment: `inventory[0]` is of type `GenericClass<Struct1>`, so `inventory[0].setIdentifier()` is specified as requiring an argument of type `Struct1`.   Your code is passing an `int`.    `GenericClass` is a templated class, true, but that doesn't mean `GenericClass<Struct1>::setIdentifier()` can accept an argument of any type - it only accepts an argument of type `Struct1`.

Comment: Makes sense, what do I need to know about constructing a solution?

Comment: Can you modify you modify `Struct1`, 2 and 3?

Comment: I can only modify the class in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it expecting Struct1

Because that is the type it was told to use.

Given the template:

```
template<typename Type>
class GenericClass
{
private:
    Type Identifier;

public:
    void setIdentifier(Type Param);
    Type getIdentifier();
};
```

The instantiation with type `Struct1` (`GenericClass<Struct1>`) generates the following implementation:

```
// Just for illustration
class GenericClassStruct1
{
private:
    Struct1 Identifier;

public:
    void setIdentifier(Struct1 Param);
    Struct1 getIdentifier();
};
```

The above class has replaced all occurrences of `Type` with `Struct1`. Now, it should be easy to see why calling `setIdentifier` expects a `Struct1` and not an `int`.

> how do I format it so I can modify the properties in any struct

There is more than one way to do this. What is the "right" way will depend on the constraints of your problem but following example shows one way.

#### Example

[Working Example](https://ideone.com/AkhHEL)

```
#include <iostream>

// Declared but not defined, specializations will provide definitions
template<typename T>
struct GenericTypeTraits;

template<typename T>
class Generic
{
public:
    using IdType = typename GenericTypeTraits<T>::IdType;

    void setIdentifier(IdType id)
    {
        mType.mIdentifier = id;
    }

    IdType getIdentifier() const
    {
        return mType.mIdentifier;
    }

private:
    T mType;
};

class Type1
{
public:
    int mIdentifier;
};

template<>
struct GenericTypeTraits<Type1>
{
    using IdType = int;
};

class Type2
{
public:
    std::string mIdentifier;
};

template<>
struct GenericTypeTraits<Type2>
{
    using IdType = std::string;
};

int main()
{
    Generic<Type1> t1[5];
    t1[0].setIdentifier(3);
    std::cout << t1[0].getIdentifier() << "\n";

    Generic<Type2> t2[5];
    t2[0].setIdentifier("3");
    std::cout << t2[0].getIdentifier() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
3
3
```

Answer (score 1):

The templated `GenericClass` defines a family of classes.   Each specialisation of `GenericClass` has its own single specialisation of `setIdentifier()`.   So `GenericClass<Struct1>` has a single `setIdentifer()` that accepts a `Struct1` but does not have a `setIdentifier()` that accepts an `int` (or any other type).    In the usage `inventory[0].setIdentifier(1)`, `inventory[0]` is of type `GenericClass<Struct1>`, and its `setIdentifier()` member function can accept a `Struct1` but not an `int`.    Hence the error message.

If I understand what you're trying to do (I'm not sure - only guessing based on your non-working code) you need to do something like;

```
template<class T> class Struct
{
   public:
      void SetIdentifier(const T &id) {Identifier = id;};
      T getIdentifier() const {return Identifier;};
    private:
       T Identifier;
       std::string Description;
       float Value;
};

template <class Type>
class GenericClass
{ 
   private:
       Struct<Type> data;
   public:
      void setIdentifier(Type Param) {data.setIdentifier(Param);};
      Type getIdentifier() const {return data.getIdentifier();};
};

int main()
{
      GenericClass<int> inventory[1000];
      inventory[0].setIdentifier(1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`Identifier` in the problematic methods refers to `GenericRecord::Identifier`, which *is* one of your structs, not *its* member named `Identifier`.  Similarly, `Type` is that struct type, not the type of its `Identifier` member.  So your methods never use the “properties” you’re trying to wrap.

The simple solution involves another template parameter for the property’s type:

```
template<class T,class P>
class GenericRecord {
  T wrapped;      // avoid confusing reuse of "Identifier"
public:
  void setIdentifier(P p) {wrapped.Identifier=p;}
  P getIdentifier() const {return wrapped.Identifier;}
};
```