# C++ template function: explicit instantiate one or more specializations

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to explicit instantiate one or more specializations of a template function?
Second, does it matter if the function is a class member?
Is it legal C++11 and also is it accepted by compilers so it doesn't come with problems?

Comment: Did you read Johannes' answer [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512910/explicit-specialization-of-template-class-member-function?rq=1), which I think is very close to what you're asking (at least the second part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to explicit instantiate one or more specializations of a template function?

Yes, however,
[temp.explicit]/5:

> For a given set of template arguments, if an explicit instantiation of a template appears after a declaration of an explicit specialization for that template, the explicit instantiation has no effect.

---

> Second, does it matter if the function is a class member?

No, AFAIK;
[temp.explicit]/1:

> A class, a function or member template specialization can be explicitly instantiated from its template. **A member function, member class or static data member of a class template can be explicitly instantiated from the member definition associated with its class template**. An explicit instantiation of a function template or member function of a class template shall not use the inline or constexpr specifiers.

Example from [temp.explicit]/3:

```
template<class T> class Array { void mf(); };
template class Array<char>;

template void Array<int>::mf();

template<class T> void sort(Array<T>& v) { /∗ ... ∗/ }
template void sort(Array<char>&);    // argument is deduced here

namespace N {
template<class T> void f(T&) { }
}
template void N::f<int>(int&);
```

---

> Is it legal C++11 and also is it accepted by compilers so it doesn't come with problems?

Well, yes, but for libraries there's always the problem of ABI compatibility; especially if different compilers have been used for library and library user (e.g. program including that library). The C++ Standard does not specify an ABI.