# template class template method specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Why does the following code fail to compile?

```
template <typename T>
struct X
{
    template <typename R>
    R default_value();
};

template <typename T>
int X<T>::default_value<int>()
{
    return -1;
}
```

it says

```
x.cpp:17:30: error: template-id ‘default_value<int>’ in declaration of primary template
x.cpp:17:5: error: prototype for ‘int X<T>::default_value()’ does not match any in class ‘X<T>’
x.cpp:13:7: error: candidate is: template<class T> template<class R> R X::default_value()
```

I also tried to do

```
template <typename T>
template <>
int X<T>::default_value<int>()
{
    return -1;
}
```

but this gives me another compilation error

```
prog.cpp:11: error: invalid explicit specialization before '>' token
prog.cpp:11: error: enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized
prog.cpp:12: error: template-id 'default_value<int>' for 'int X<T>::default_value()' does not match any template declaration
```

I also tried doing the same for structures

```
template <typename T>
struct X
{
    template <typename R> struct default_value;
};

template <typename T>
template <>
struct X<T>::default_value<int>
{
    static int get() { return -1; }
};
```

same issue.

How to solve that?

Comment: why template on the return type, function cannot be overloaded based on return type.

Comment: I'm not overloading it, I'm doing specialization. Well, but basically I started from structure specialization and encountered the same error.

Comment: The same for non-method function works fine. http://ideone.com/C1YTBa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot explicitly specialize member templates. Consider:

```
template <class T>
struct X
{
  template <class U> struct Y;
};
```

...Now (imagine we could do this):

```
template <class T>
  template <>
  struct X<T>::Y<int>
{};
```

...For X of which T are we explicitly specializing?

What if, after the point of definition of our explicit specialization, someone does this in one compilation unit...

```
void foo()
{
  X<int>::Y<int> xy;
}
```

... and then this in another...(valid code, btw).

```
template <>
  template<>
  struct X<int>::Y<int>
{};

void foo()
{
  X<int>::Y<int> xy;
}
```

... which would imply multiple definitions of the same class???

As mentioned previously, this is treated well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512910/explicit-specialization-of-template-class-member-function)

Now, considering that the default value actually depends on the type T, perhaps one can get it from the type T.

```
template <class T>
struct X
{
  static T defaultValue(){ return T::defaultValue(); }
};
```

or better yet, one could change the behavior of defaultValue based on whether T has the member defaultValue.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
template <>
int X<T>::default_value<int>()
{
    return -1;
}
```

should be fine. [Similar topic...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512910/explicit-specialization-of-template-class-member-function)

Comment: I tried that already, it says `x.cpp:17:11: error: invalid explicit specialization before ‘>’ token
x.cpp:17:11: error: enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized
x.cpp:18:5: error: template-id ‘default_value<int>’ for ‘int X<T>::default_value()’ does not match any template declaration
`

Comment: @axe: What kind of compiler are you using?

Comment: Locally gcc 4.6.3, The same issue reproduces on ideone.com with gcc 4.8.1