# Template class Member function specialization

Tags: c++, templates

Before someone has marked this question as duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512910/explicit-specialization-of-template-class-member-function) ,please let me explain my problem.
I have a class template with member functions which are not templates.I want to have additional version of the body of such functions for a specific class template param.In my case it can be only two variations: "true" or "false"

**Example:**

```
  template <bool IsEven>
  class EvenOddProcessor{

      public:

          bool ProcessEvenOdd();

  };
   //Default definition:
  template<bool IsEven>    
  inline bool EvenOddProcessor<IsEven>::ProcessEvenOdd()
  {

        return false;

  }

  //Now I want to define the special case of the function
  //when the class template param is true:    
  inline bool EvenOddProcessor<true>::ProcessEvenOdd()
  {

        return true;

  }
```

Now,this works with MSVC compilers and doesn't with GCC.This is unsurprising  because GCC is always more strict about C++ standard,which as far as I understand,doesn't allow member function specialization.However based on the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512910/explicit-specialization-of-template-class-member-function) what I am trying to do still should be possible with some template magic.None of the solutions in that answers worked in my case.

Comment: You need a `template <>` phrase before a specialization

Comment: It doesn't work on GCC as it is member specialization which is not allowed

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki and you are completely right  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to mark it as a specialisation with `template <>`:

```
template <>
inline bool EvenOddProcessor<true>::ProcessEvenOdd()
{
    return true;
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e738c8b0eaf2caf)

Comment: Which is almost identical to the actual error message! :) `error: specializing member 'EvenOddProcessor<true>::ProcessEvenOdd' requires 'template<>' syntax`

Comment: Shame on me!! I confused it with the template member functions specialization.Yeah,adding 'template<>' syntax indeed works in this case!