# Simple template class member function specialization that returns a value

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I am trying to call a template class member function specialization that returns a value from within the class's constructor, and I cannot seem to find the correct syntax (if it exists).  Below is my code, and, below that, the error messages from the compiler (not the linker).

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};

class B {};

template <typename T>
class C
{
    public:
        C()
        {
            std::cout << "C constructed." << std::endl;
            std::cout << name() << std::endl;;
        }
        template constexpr const char * name();
};

template <> const char * C<A>::name() { return "You got an A."; }
template <> const char * C<B>::name() { return "You got a B."; }


int main()
{
    C<A> c_a;
    C<B> c_b;
    return 0;
}
```

Error messages:
g++ -std=c++11 -o t1 t1.cpp 
t1.cpp:19:18: error: expected ‘<’ before ‘constexpr’
         template constexpr const char * name();
                  ^
t1.cpp:22:26: error: template-id ‘name<>’ for ‘const char* C::name()’ does not match any template declaration
 template <> const char * C::name() { return "You got an A."; }
                          ^
t1.cpp:22:37: note: saw 1 ‘template<>’, need 2 for specializing a member function template
 template <> const char * C::name() { return "You got an A."; }
                                     ^
t1.cpp:23:26: error: template-id ‘name<>’ for ‘const char* C::name()’ does not match any template declaration
 template <> const char * C::name() { return "You got a B."; }
                          ^
t1.cpp:23:37: note: saw 1 ‘template<>’, need 2 for specializing a member function template
 template <> const char * C::name() { return "You got a B."; }

I have searched and found *many* discussions about code that elicits this error message, but neither the cases nor the advice seem to be close enough to be relevant.  Also, if I do  not try to return anything from the specialized member function--if it has return type **void** and simply prints to **cout**--then it works as I would expect, i.e., I see the printed text with the right values.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?  If so, how?  Thanks!

Comment: The `name()` function isn't itself a template, so why the `template`?

Comment: You are right.  What I actually intended was a member function of a specialization of the class, but I was using syntax as if it were a specialization of a template function of that template class.  This was my mistake. (See my solution.)  Thanks.

Comment: Oops!  While I was writing the above reply, somebody posted a solution equivalent to the one I had found.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Syntax would be:

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
    public:
        C()
        {
            std::cout << "C constructed." << std::endl;
            std::cout << name() << std::endl;;
        }
        constexpr const char* name();
};

template <> constexpr const char * C<A>::name() { return "You got an A."; }
template <> constexpr const char * C<B>::name() { return "You got a B."; }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bde5f4d66b2e9fa)

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work with my GCC:
 $ g++ -std=c++11 -o t1 t1.cpp 
t1.cpp: In member function ‘constexpr const char* C<T>::name() const [with T = A]’:
t1.cpp:60:36: error: enclosing class of constexpr non-static member function ‘constexpr const char* C<T>::name() const [with T = A]’ is not a literal type

Comment: You got warning: *"'`C<A>`' is not literal because: `C<A>` is not an aggregate, does not have a trivial default constructor, and has no `constexpr` constructor that is not a copy or move constructor"*. So you have to satisfy at least one point as providing `constexpr` constructor ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2a5fdacc5b75351)).

Answer (score 2):

You are complicating it a bit.  There is no need for "template" in the function declaration.  It's just an ordinary function that happens to be inside a class template, and you want to specialize it for certain T's.  Here's a way to do that:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};
class B {};

template <typename T>
class C {
public:
    C() {
        std::cout << "C constructed." << std::endl;
        std::cout << name() << std::endl;;
    }
    static constexpr const char * name();
};

template <> constexpr const char * C<A>::name() { return "You got an A."; }
template <> constexpr const char * C<B>::name() { return "You got a B."; }

int main() {
    C<A> c_a;
    C<B> c_b;
}
```

Comment: You are right!  It did not need to be an instance member function at all.  I just did not know how to get the right syntax for a static function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I found a solution to the *exact* problem I had posted--i.e., using a member function instead of a static (or global) function, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512910/explicit-specialization-of-template-class-member-function).

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};
class B {};

template <typename T>
class C
{
    template <typename U> struct type {};
    public:
        C()
        {
            std::cout << "C constructed." << std::endl;
            std::cout << name<T>() << std::endl;;
        }
        template <typename U> constexpr const char * name()
        {
            return name(type<U>());
        }


    private:
        template <typename U> constexpr const char * name(type<U>) {}
        constexpr const char * name(type<A>) { return "You got an A."; }
        constexpr const char * name(type<B>) { return "You got an B."; }
};

int main()
{
    C<A> c_a;
    C<B> c_b;
    return 0;
}
```