# C++ template class, changing behaviour of class method based on typename

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a template class whose method I am trying to specialize based on the typename in class. A skeleton of the code is as follows:

```
template <typename C> class Instance {
  protected:
    C data;
  public:
    void populateData();
    /* want to change the behavior of populateData() depending on C */
};
```

How do I achieve the above stated goal?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization#Members_of_specializations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [explicit specialization of template class member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512910/explicit-specialization-of-template-class-member-function)

Comment: In reality I have multiple class members and functions that retain the same implementation - do I have to reimplement all those functions that do not change too. This is one of the source of my confusion when I try to specialize the class itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
template <typename C> class Instance {
  protected:
    C data;
  public:
    void populateData();
    /* want to change the behavior of populateData() depending on C */
};

template<>
void Instance<int>::populateData() {
    // Do something when C is int
}
```

You can specialize the function for any type you want.

Comment: Note: Only works with fully specialization: `template <typename T> void Instance<std::vector<T>>::populateData()` won't be possible.