# C++ Specializing single member function

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Problems with class template member specialization.

I have a simple class and I want specialize a single member function. I'm doing like this:

```
template <class T>
class Object
{
public:
    Object() {}

    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "It's the template" << std::endl;
    }
    // ...
};

template<>
void Object<int>::print() const
{
    std::cout << "It's an int" << std::endl;
}
```

which ends up in a compile error for multiple definition of the member function.

If just one source file includes the header everything is fine.

If two files include the header I get the following error:

> /home/marc/QtProjects/QtAsp-Service/build-aspservice-Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/../src/Asp/aspobject.h:34: Fehler: multiple definition of `Asp2::print()'; main.o:/home/marc/QtProjects/QtAsp-Service/build-aspservice-Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/../src/Asp/aspobject.h:34: first defined here

This this possible in general? If yes, what is wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact error message from your compiler.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not currently possible to specialize just a member function of a template class; you need to specialize the entire class. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512910/explicit-specialization-of-template-class-member-function) for a discussion of the issue.

Comment: You have a typo in your specialization, should `AspObject`, just be `Object`? Is [this](https://ideone.com/Qbq0CI) the behaviour your are looking for?

Comment: @NathanPierson I think it is possible, the function in question is not a template function, so this questions is not quite the same. You can definitely specialize specific member functions of templated classes.

Comment: Oh, interesting! Thanks for the correction, @FantasticMrFox

Comment: @NathanPierson It is possible in more modern C++ implementations. See below

Comment: I don't think it's a modernity issue, it's that I didn't realize that the rule was only for templated member functions of templated classes, not all member functions of templated classes.

Comment: Should we just close this as a typo or is there something we don't see?

Comment: @ Fantastic Mr Fox: You are right with the type, but this was not problem. The template class lives in a header file. If just one source file includes the header everything is fine. If two files include the header I get the following error: /home/marc/QtProjects/QtAsp-Service/build-aspservice-Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/../src/Asp/aspobject.h:34: Fehler: multiple definition of `Asp2<int>::print()'; main.o:/home/marc/QtProjects/QtAsp-Service/build-aspservice-Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/../src/Asp/aspobject.h:34: first defined here

Comment: @marca you should put the specialization in a .cpp file, I believe

Answer (score 3):

Your way is correct, but fully specialized member is no longer template, so no longer implicitly inline.

You have to add `inline` if you keep definition in header, or split declaration (in header) and definition (in cpp).

```
template<>
inline void Object<int>::print()
{
    std::cout << "It's an int" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that the template class is defined in a seperate header file. If only one source file includes the header it works. If two or more source files include the header GCC throws a multiple definition error. Is there a other way of doing it?

Comment: You should not ask questions in an answer. The answer section is for solutions to the question.

Comment: Sorry won't do ist again.

Comment: You probably need to edit your question to add the additional information. And to fix the code it is currently confusing with the `Object` and `AspObject`