# Template specialization for template function members combined with class template

Tags: c++, function, templates, template-specialization

Given the following:

```
class MyClass
{
   public:
      template <typename T, typename U = T>
      void doSomething(T) {}
   private:
      double parser;
};

template<>
inline void MyClass::doSomething<bool>(bool) {}
template<>
inline void MyClass::doSomething<int, double>(int) {}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   MyClass foo;
   foo.doSomething<bool>(true);
   foo.doSomething<int, double>(10);
   return 0;
}
```

This works fine.

However now I want to introduce a class template in order to use a template parameter instead of `ParserClass`, like so:

```
template<typename P>
class MyClass
{
   public:
      template <typename T, typename U = T>
      void doSomething(T) {}
   private:
      P parser;
};

template<>
inline void MyClass::doSomething<bool>(bool) {}
template<>
inline void MyClass::doSomething<int, double>(int) {}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   MyClass<double> foo;
   foo.doSomething<bool>(true);
   foo.doSomething<int, double>(10);
   return 0;
}
```

Which, however, does no longer work:

```
test.cpp:12:13: error: 'MyClass' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
inline void MyClass::doSomething<bool>(bool) {}
            ^
test.cpp:2:7: note: 'MyClass' declared here
class MyClass
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Is it even possible? How do I combine the member function template parameters and the class template parameters in the above example?

Comment: What "does no longer work" mean?

Comment: Good point. Might have added the issues. However its probably going to be couple of miles of template error code text. I'll see if I can get something useful into the post.

Comment: any error message is better than no error message. Please also read about [mcve]

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: You can't specialize a member function template without specializing the class template itself.

Comment: Okay so this would mean I would have to have an implementation for every `P` for the two `doSomething` methods?
Thats a bit sad, since I wanted the `doSomething`s to be implemented exactly once (the code would be the same for all `P`).
Any other way to achieve the same but without implementing multiple versions of the same `doSomething`?

Comment: What about using free (friends) functions instead of member ones? Typically, such problems can be solver by introducing an additional level of indirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specialize a function that is a member of a templated class, you need two `template<>` declarations. Furthermore, you need to specify the `typename` for `MyClass`:

```
template<> template<>
inline void MyClass<some_type>::doSomething<bool>(bool) { ... }
template<> template<>
inline void MyClass<some_type>::doSomething<int, double>(int) { ... }
```

Comment: Okay so this would mean I would have to have an implementation for every `P` for the two `doSomething` methods?
Thats a bit sad, since I wanted the `doSomething`s to be implemented exactly once (the code would be the same for all `P`).
Any other way to achieve the same but without implementing multiple versions of the same `doSomething`?

Comment: You [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5513109/6649786) specialize a member function without specializing its parent class.

Comment: Ok so how could I solve it? I will have around 30 `T`/`U` specializations, which will be the same for all `P`.
So I need a way to plug a generic `P` into `MyClass`.

Comment: The answer I've posted a link to suggests a solution. The other two answers below it also demonstrate some hacks to help you get around this.