# Can I make separate definitions of function template members of a class template?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization, function-templates

Here's a minimal code example to show what I'm attempting that works, but not how I'd like it to:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
struct string_tag {
    using R=const std::string;
};

struct int_tag {
    using R=const int;
};

template <bool TS>
class Wibble {
    public:
    template<typename TAG>
    typename TAG::R getValue(TAG);
};

template <bool TS>
template <typename TAG>
typename TAG::R Wibble<TS>::getValue(TAG) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same<TAG, string_tag>::value) {
        return "hello";
    }
    
    if constexpr (std::is_same<TAG, int_tag>::value) {
        return 42;
    }
}

// instantiate classes
template class Wibble<true>;
template class Wibble<false>;

int main () {
    Wibble<true> tw;
    Wibble<false> fw;
    std::cout << "tw string: " << tw.getValue(string_tag{}) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "tw int: " << tw.getValue(int_tag{}) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fw string: " <<fw.getValue(string_tag{}) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fw int: " << fw.getValue(int_tag{}) << std::endl;
}
```

[example in godbolt here](https://godbolt.org/z/7eb1hvPr1)

The part I want to change is the ugly function template definition with all the `constexpr` logic. I'd like to be able to define the different specializations in `TAG` standalone, but doing this gives me `redefinition of ...` errors.

Syntax like the following would be nice:

```
template<bool TS>
template<>
string_tag::R Wibble<TS>::getValue(string_tag) {
  return "hello";
}
```

but computer says "no".

Comment: It looks like you want [`concepts`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts).  Are you up for C++20 ? Re:  _"computer says "no""_ +1

Comment: it's probably time I dragged myself kicking & screaming into c++20 :-) Thanks!

Comment: Don't take my word for it - I'm just shouting out buzzwords :-) I'm pretty much happy at C++17 myself. :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [explicit specialization of template class member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512910/explicit-specialization-of-template-class-member-function)

Comment: it looks like it could. I'll try it out. thanks!

Comment: That other question requires the template to be specialized first, as described, which isn't the case here. Given that `getValue()` does not depend on the `TS` parameter, it should be implemented as a template function separately, that can be specialized normally. The class template can still define its own `getValue()` method that does nothing but call the "real" `getvalue`. I expect modern C++ compilers to optimize away the extra function call.

Comment: Why do you need template method instead of just overloading it on the needed type?

Comment: I want different return types - that's what the tag dispatching gets me.

Comment: @VorpalSword You can get different return types via overloading so long as you're still using the tag as a function argument. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K5KK3WMq9). Does this achieve what you're looking for?

Comment: that'd work but I prefer @alanger's answer. Thanks all the same though :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I gave it a thought, read language specs etc. and the following things come to my mind:

1. Class template has to be specialized in order to specialize member function template. Period. This cannot be overcome with concepts, or at least I haven't found a way. I guess you don't want to replicate the code for each case of TS. Maybe it can be done automagically with some Alexandrescu-style metaprogramming techniques, but I can't think of anything right off the bat.
2. Overloads instead of templates are a good alternative but I'm guessing you'd like to be able to add them out-of-line, instead of inside the class...
3. Then I recalled David Wheeler: “All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection." So let's add one:

```cpp
namespace detail
{
template<typename TAG> auto getValue(TAG);

template<>
auto getValue<string_tag>(string_tag)
{
    return "hi";
}


template<>
auto getValue<int_tag>(int_tag)
{
    return 42;
}

template<>
auto getValue<double_tag>(double_tag)
{
    return 1324.2;
}

}

template<bool TS>
template<typename TAG>
auto Wibble<TS>::getValue(TAG t)
{
    return detail::getValue(t);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/GsPK4MP8M
Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks so much! this worked perfectly. A rare example of winning the "be reasonable and do it my way!" interaction with compilers ;-)